# State of matrix 'reverting back'

Tags: elixir

I am trying to process data in a 2D list. I understand that all objects are immutable. My recursive calls are backtracking and state is disappearing. What is the standard approach for dealing with this, when you have no state?

```
defmodule Euler do
  def euler_15() do
    grid = create_2d_list(10, 10)
    # write out 1's to the first row
    grid = write_out_first_row(grid, 0)
    grid = write_out_first_column(grid, 0)
    fill_out_remainder(grid, 1, 1)
  end

  def fill_out_remainder(grid, 10, _) do
    IO.puts("finale to fill_out_remainder")
  end

  def write_out_column(grid, row, 10) do
    IO.puts("finale! to write out column is running for row: #{row}")
  end

  def write_out_column(grid, row, col) do
    IO.puts("*** write out column is running for column: #{col} and row: #{row}")
    IO.puts("Reading from this grid state")
    IO.inspect(grid)
    cell_above = get_element(grid, row-1, col) 
    IO.puts("value from column above is: #{cell_above}")
    cell_left = get_element(grid, row, col-1)
    IO.puts("value from left cell is: #{cell_left}")
    grid = set_element(grid,row,col,cell_above+cell_left)
    IO.inspect(grid)
    write_out_column(grid, row, col+1)
  end

  def write_out_row(grid, row) do
    write_out_column(grid, row, 1)
  end

  def fill_out_remainder(grid, row_ct, col_ct) do
    write_out_row(grid, row_ct)
    fill_out_remainder(grid, row_ct + 1, col_ct)
  end

  def write_out_first_row(grid, 10) do
    grid
  end

  def write_out_first_row(grid, counter) do
    grid = set_element(grid, 0, counter, 1)
    write_out_first_row(grid, counter + 1)
  end

  def write_out_first_column(grid, 10) do
    grid
  end

  def write_out_first_column(grid, counter) do
    grid = set_element(grid, counter, 0, 1)
    write_out_first_column(grid, counter + 1)
  end

  def create_2d_list(rows, cols) do
    for _ <- 1..rows, do: for(_ <- 1..cols, do: nil)
  end

  def get_element(grid, r, c) do
    # first step - extract the row
    the_row = Enum.at(grid, r)
    # now get the value
    Enum.at(the_row,c)
  end

  def set_element(grid, r, c, new_value) do
    # stage 1 - extract the row
    the_row = Enum.at(grid, r)
    # stage 2 - update the row
    the_row = List.replace_at(the_row, c, new_value)
    # stage 3 - update the 2d lists row to be changed
    # with the updated row
    grid = List.replace_at(grid, r, the_row)
    grid
  end
end

Euler.euler_15()
```

Comment: It's a systemic anomoly. You must return to the source, reinserting the prime program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler 15 is a typical dynamic programming problem. Here are my approaches. (All indices are 1-based)

### Top-down DP (A.K.A. Memoization)

The "standard" way is to make the recursive call
take the state along with all other args,
and return both the result of that recursion
and the updated state.

```
defmodule Euler do
  def euler_15(rows, cols) do
    # The first arg is the "state",
    # which I prefer to call it "memo".
    {routes, _memo} = solve(%{}, rows, cols, 1, 1)
    routes
  end

  # The recursive function should return
  # both the number of routes
  # and the updated memo.
  defp solve(memo, rows, _cols, rows, _j), do: {1, memo}
  defp solve(memo, _rows, cols, _i, cols), do: {1, memo}

  defp solve(memo, rows, cols, i, j) do
    case memo[{i, j}] do
      nil ->
        {right, memo} = solve(memo, rows, cols, i, j + 1)
        {down, memo} = solve(memo, rows, cols, i + 1, j)
        routes = right + down
        memo = Map.put(memo, {i, j}, routes)
        {routes, memo}

      routes ->
        {routes, memo}
    end
  end
end
```

### Top-down DP V2

This is my way of solving memoization problems by bringing back the mutability. This is easier to code than V1 and runs faster, too.

```
defmodule Euler do
  def euler_15(rows, cols) do
    # Because we are going to use process dictionary as the memo,
    # and we don't want to pollute the process dictionary of the caller,
    # we just spawn a child process to do all the nasty work.
    Task.async(fn ->
      solve(rows, cols, 1, 1)
    end)
    |> Task.await()
  end

  # The process dictionary is the memo,
  # so we don't need to pass in the memo any more.
  # We don't need to return the memo, either.
  defp solve(rows, _cols, rows, _j), do: 1
  defp solve(_rows, cols, _i, cols), do: 1

  defp solve(rows, cols, i, j) do
    memoized({i, j}, fn ->
      right = solve(rows, cols, i, j + 1)
      down = solve(rows, cols, i + 1, j)
      right + down
    end)
  end

  defp memoized(key, fun) do
    case Process.get(key) do
      nil ->
        val = fun.()
        Process.put(key, val)
        val

      val ->
        val
    end
  end
end
```

### Bottom-up DP

You still need to keep tracking of the updated memo.

```
defmodule Euler do
  def euler_15(rows, cols) do
    memo = for i <- 1..rows, into: %{} do
      {{i, 1}, 1}
    end

    memo = for j <- 1..cols, into: memo do
      {{1, j}, 1}
    end

    memo = for i <- 2..rows, j <- 2..cols, reduce: memo do
      memo -> Map.put(memo, {i, j}, memo[{i - 1, j}] + memo[{i, j - 1}])
    end

    memo[{rows, cols}]
  end
end
```